# Binding dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got a requirement to bind a dropdownlist using db values.I gave that dropdownlist  datasource as a list of class, ie `ddlUser.datasource=List <User>;`

The class user contains following properties `UserID`, `Firstname` and `Lastname`.

Its datavalue field is `UserID`.

I want to show the text of dropdown as a string ie `Firstname+" " + Lastname`.

Comment: why people dont understand that they should accept answers if they ask Questions !!! when some is putting efforts to answer anybodies query at least accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to do this, add a property to your user name FullName

```
public string FullName 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", Firstname, LastName);
    }
}
```

or use a foreach to create a list of listitem with id as the value and the concantaned name as the text.

```
List<ListItem> userList = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (User u in Users)
{                        
   userList.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("{0} {1}", u.Firstname, u.LastName), u.UserID ));
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without adding a property ie from code behind

Comment: second part of answer, loop through a list of users and manually set the text and value of each list item, then bind this to your dropdown.

Comment: I like this answer better actually, it's better to have a property than a ToString() to get the full name.

Answer (score 0):

override tostring method in User class so it's like this

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return Firstname + " " + Lastname;
}
```

When you bind make sure you have an populated list of users i.e.

```
List<User> list = new List<User>();
// populate list
ddlUser.DataSource = list;
ddlUser.DataBind();
```